# Timeout and cancel tasks in ExecutionService in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to execute some tasks in parallel, in such a way that the main calling thread will not be blocked. Each task will be terminated if timeout occurs and I will have the ability to cancel all the tasks at once if user changed his mind.

What I came up with is:

The main thread calls new DownloadWatcherThread (so it won't be blocked).
DownloadWatcherThread has run method like this:

```
public void run() {
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    futures = new ArrayList<Future>();
    for(Component component: components) {

        PackageDownloader downloader = new PackageDownloader(component);
        futures.add(executorService.submit(downloader));
    }

    for(Future future: futures){
        try {
            future.get(8, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            future.cancel(true);
        }
    }

    executorService.shutdown();
}

public void cancelTasks(){      
    executorService.shutdownNow();
}
```

So, the question is this the correct way to achieve all the 3 ingredients?

1. Not blocking the calling thread
2. Timeout task if it takes long time
3. Cancelling the whole thing if the user wishes so

Answer (score 0):

A few comments:

- Your current design will block until the first download is complete, then the second, and so on. If the first download takes the full eight hours then you've potentially missed an opportunity to react to the completion of the other downloads. If this is a problem, you may need a redesign.
- Your `cancelTasks` method relies only on the executor service to stop the threads. Are you confident that the `PackageDownloader` respects thread interrupts? If not, then your threads may not actually stop.

You may wish to post your code over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html), which handles the queing of finished future tasks. Use the [poll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html#poll%28%29) method to poll for finished tasks.